# Dealing with security patches in docker

Tags: git, docker, patch

I've build a Dockerfile and docker-compose to work against the tags of an open source project. Every couple of months, the project team releases tags named using the a "MAJOR.minor.patch-relase" syntax (ie: 3.1.2-4) and each time the tag is created, dockerHub generates a new image, so I just need to stop my container, change the version in docker-compose and rise the container again to get the last version of the patched code (or use "latest" tag). Till here, all works like a charm, but...

The problem is, sometimes, between tags, some zero-day security patches are released (but not the tag) so one or multiple patches need to be applied over my containers before the new image is generated.

So, I'm wondering what are the pros/cons of these strategies like:

1. Adding git again to the container to cherry-pick the specific changes over my existing
   container?
2. Avoid git (to keep the container lightweight) and just overwrite the files that change (for
   instance, with a bash script that uses wget to do the job)?
3. Cherry-pick outside the container and apply the changes to the
   specific files.
4. Integrate (via docker-compose) a magic additinal project to keep the track of those changes?
5. Ask the project leader to release more often?
6. None of the above...

Thanks for your help.

Comment: First, note that the initial assumption of your question might be questioned − `sometimes, between tags, some zero-day security patches are released (but not the tag)` − as a zero-day security patch would probably deserve a tag or patch-release(?)

Comment: Next, even if you fully described the context in your question, it probably needs to be rephrased (i.e., edited), so that it does not induce subjective/opinion-based answers, see e.g. [Why are some questions closed?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions). (Typically, avoiding phrasing a question such as `What is the best practice here?` on StackOverflow.)

Comment: Why do you have to use tags to identify a version in your docker-compose?  Any git commit hash should work.

Comment: @ErikMD about your first comment, does it means that you would suggest going with 5?
It will be also my proposal. If you use a "MAJOR.minor.patch" compatibility or semantic versioning , make a lot of sense to release on every security patch, isn't it?

About your second comment, English is not my mother tongue, so sorry in advance if I didn't express it properly. What I'm trying to express is, that I feel this needs to be quite common problem so I'm quite sure there is a pattern o good practice to follow.

Would be better expressed in this way?

Comment: @jingx I build those dockerfiles and compose to work on production, so I felt like I didn't need more granularity than the one I got from tags.

Rebuilding the dockerfile/composes to work with commits instead of tags is also a solution... even it won't let me cherry-pick (for instance) last 3 security patches and logic won't be as clear for sysOps (is easier to refer a tag version -that match with project version- than a commit hash). And this solution won't help if you have to deal with patches published in different commits.

Comment: @MarcBria yes, strategy 5 also LGTM: if the project uses semantic versioning, making a point release for each security patch seems very OK. Regarding your 2nd question (related to [my 2nd comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64175125/dealing-with-security-patches-in-docker?noredirect=1#comment113489026_64175125)), it wasn't a matter of English; I was just underlining the fact that "subjective questions" are a bit frown upon on StackOverflow… (So instead of asking "What's the best solution?" or so, you might ask something more factual, e.g. "What are the pros/cons of these strategies"?)

Comment: I still don't get why you have to "rebuild the dockerfile/compose to work with commits". It should just work by referencing a commit. Regardless though, you can always install git during your build, do whatever cherry-picking you need to do, and uninstall git before finishing the image.

Comment: @jingx `It should just work by referencing a commit`: are you sure? because docker tags (nor Docker Hub tags) are not mapped to Git commits by default. Granted, one can **choose** to auto-build a given Git branch **and** automatically tag an image with a SHA1 or so, but this is mostly a configuration-management choice, and whether this automatic SHA1 tagging is feasible or not depends on the build infrastructure itself (e.g., it is not feasible currently with Docker Hub automated builds IINM).

Comment: Anyway, even if manual git operations are indeed possible during the image build step (installing git first, and removing it in the end), IMHO it seems simpler to make **git push** trigger a build of the image (that does not contain git) using the proper work-tree provided by the CI/CD environment, rather than manually triggering a build of an image (installing git first) performing some *git clone/git cherry-pick*.

Comment: @ErikMD I see where my confusion came from. I misread OP's "tags of an open source project" and took "tag" to mean git tags.  Never mind...

Comment: Thanks @ErikMD to clarify. Is exacly as you explained.
It works smothly because tags between gitHub, dockerHub, Dockerfile and docker-compose are sync.

(BTW, post edited. Thanks.)

Comment: But @jingx approach would be also possible changing the way I'm building my Dockerfiles to ask for the code and also changing my docker-compose. Link to the project, just in case somebody is curious: https://github.com/pkp/docker-ojs/tree/master/versions/3_2_1-1/alpine/apache/php73

Comment: Anyway, seams quite obvius that "5. Ask the project leader to release more often?" (or at least, each time a security patch is released).

Even I read a lot, it's my first time asking in stackoverflow.
How should I check the solution and credit the author?

Comment: Just in case somebody arrive to this post someday and find those thoughts useful, here you have an example of a Dockerfile that takes patches as arguments to build the image:

"...sometimes has issues that you may need PRs or custom patches to address, this image supports applying patches automatically. You can list a series of Github PR numbers as a build argument (e.g. docker build --build-args BUILD_PRS="7046 7399 7409"), or as an environment variable on a specific container (in the MAUTIC_PRS environment variable.)"

https://github.com/dirtsimple/mautic-server#patches-and-pull-requests

Comment: @MarcBria "checking the solution and crediting its author" is not possible for mere comments: on StackOverflow this just works by accepting (and voting) an answer. But even if there is currently none, given you figured out a possible good (simple) solution was item 5., and the link you posted provided another interesting solution, feel free to post an answer to your question! (This approach is fully OK on StackOverflow: you can typically accept your own answer, for example.)